# Is System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider FIPS 140-2 complaint?

Tags: c#, cryptography, fips

we are using this System.Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider .net lib. 
we need to make sure that if its is compliant with FIPS 140-2

here is the link from MS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation#_microsoft_fips_140

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the operating system.  This .NET object is really just a wrapper around cryptographic services provided by the OS, and the algorithm could potentially change at any time.

Refer to the [CryptGenRandom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) documentation:

> In Windows Vista with Service Pack 1 (SP1) and later, an implementation of the AES counter-mode based PRNG specified in NIST Special Publication 800-90 is used. In Windows Vista, Windows Storage Server 2003, and Windows XP, the PRNG specified in Federal Information Processing Standard (FIPS) 186-2 is used.

Comment: there is the content on the link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/fips-140-validation#_microsoft_fips_140, It says that classes that end with "CryptoServiceProvider" are FIPS validated. Is my understanding is correct, that RNGCryptoServiceProvider is FIPS validated

Comment: @GauravLad Note that FIPS validation is only enforced when the corresponding local/group policy is enabled on the machine.  This setting is turned OFF by default.  To be absolutely certain of FIPS-compliance, you may need to enable that policy.  I should also mention than the MD5 hash algorithm, sometimes used for detecting file changes, is not FIPS compliant and will start throwing exceptions when this security policy is enabled.

Comment: If you go to enable the FIPS mode, you will see below instruction "System Cryptography : Use FIPS complaint algorithums for encryption,hashing and Signing" It is not saying anything about Random number generation algorithums.